# How to properly use Class-Path mechanism in Java EE 7 application modules

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, ear, manifest.mf

I'm curious about how to properly use Class-Path mechanism in *portable* Java EE 7 multimodule application.

Must EJB module reference 3rd party libraries, placed in `lib` folder of the EAR, in its MANIFEST.MF Class-Path?

To me, it looks like explicit references to them are not needed, because Java EE specification (EE.8.4.1 "Assembling a Java EE Application", item 3.e) states:

> Make sure that each component in the application properly describes any
>   dependencies it may have on other components in the application. A Java
>   EE application should not assume that all components in the application
>   will be available on the class path of the application at run time. Each
>   component might be loaded into a separate class loader with a separate
>   namespace. If the classes in a JAR file depend on classes in another JAR
>   file, the first JAR file should reference the second JAR file using the ClassPath
>   mechanism. A notable exception to this rule is JAR files located in the
>   WEB-INF/lib directory of a web application. All such JAR files are
>   included in the class path of the web application at runtime; explicit
>   references to them using the Class-Path mechanism are not needed.
>   Another exception to this rule is JAR files located in the library directory
>   (usually named lib) in the application package.

But I found advises to add references to 3rd party libraries to Class-Path of EJB module, when I was googling this question. And this confuses me a little bit.

I'll appreciate any help!

Comment: FWIW, those references you found recommending "to add references to 3rd party libraries to Class-Path of EJB module" probably date back a time when there was no formal "lib" module in an EAR file (prior to Java EE 5).

Comment: @SteveC, it's absolutely possible. Thnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it depends on the way your dependencies are loaded.

if they are loaded at the ear level (shared between all ejb modules) you don't need to specify anything in the ejb-jar manifest (cf. Parent First delegation model), otherwise if you want your module dependencies to be specific to the module (and so isolated), you'll have to explicitly reference them in the manifest.

here is a good article :http://www.developer.com/java/ejb/article.php/10931_3670496_2/Packaging-EJB-3-Applications.htm

Comment: Thank you! The article is really good.
Just to clarify for myself, if some JAR is placed in EAR's `lib` directory, than it's available to all modules packaged in the EAR, otherwise it's available only for modules having appropriate reference in their manifests. Right?

Comment: third parties dependencies nested in ejb-jar modules must be referenced to be classloaded if this is your question. Otherwise i suppose that using absolute or relative path resolving lib outside of the jar may work. Class loading policies also depends on the application server...

Comment: I mean, that as I understand, EAR class loader loads all JARs in `lib` directory. And we don't need to explicitly specify anything in the EJB module manifest to access this JARs' classes :)